# Reinstalling rabbitmq causing a permission issue

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'm getting the following issue when I do

`rabbitmq-server`

I'm running on mac os x. rabbitmq version 3.5.4.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall rabbitmq without issues with brew, but end up here with the following error every time. Guidance is appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_back_up_mnesia_dir,{"/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost",
                                  "/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-upgrade-backup",
                                  eacces}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_upgrade,take_backup,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,111}]},
    {rabbit_upgrade,ensure_backup_taken,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,100}]},
    {rabbit_upgrade,maybe_upgrade_mnesia,0,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_upgrade.erl"},{line,142}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,328}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,353}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_back_up_mnesia_dir,{"/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost","/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-upgrade-backup",eacces}}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eacces` is a permission problem.

Try to execute it using `sudo rabbitmq-server`

**Edit**

RabbitMQ does not need the `sudo` rights. 
The default folders where RMQ writes (in this case) need the `sudo` rights.

But you can overload the default folders reading the documentation.

I usually override this:

```
export RABBITMQ_PID_FILE=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/data/rmq.pid
export RABBITMQ_BASE=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4
export RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/data/logs
export RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/data/db
export RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/plugins
export RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_EXPAND_DIR=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/plugins/expands
export RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE=/Users/gabriele/programs/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/enabled_plugin
```

and I don't need to use `sudo`

Please read this https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html for more info about.

Comment: Works with sudo rabbitmq-server now... But I thought rabbitmq doesn't require sudo access... Is there way to chage this?